# Wrapping Text in a Container

Tags: dart, flutter

#### issue

I am trying to wrap text within a Container. I want the text to add an ellipsis when it reaches the bottom right of its Container. However, using `TextOverflow.ellipsis` puts an ellipsis on the first line, but does not wrap in the Container. How can I achieve this effect?

#### code

```
Widget _cardIfImage(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
      child: new Container(
        height: cardMaxHeight,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: new Image.network(urlToImage),
            ),
            new Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10.0,
                  ),
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: new Container(
                            child: new Text(
                          title,
                          // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        )),
                      ),
                      new Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: new Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child: new Text(source),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of now wrapping text to a parent is not possible. You can simply specify [`maxLines`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html) property along with the `TextOverFlow.ellipses`.